# Expand and collapse menu, without taking user to top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image button, and I am using JavaScript to EXPAND and COLLAPSE a menu (by toggling between a class that has `display: none`). The toggle works fine (see the code below). However, whenever I click the button, it takes the user back to the very top of the page. I just want the "click" to expand and collapse the menu and keep the user at the location they currently are. How can I achieve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass()
    {
        $('div#mainmenu_wrap').toggleClass('hidemenu');
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="changeClass()">
<img src="images/menu_icon2.png" width="33" height="33"  />
</a>
```

Comment: That comes because of your empty anchor tag (#). Any reason you have to keep your href? A simple solution is to make your JS trigger look like a link, using pure CSS.

Comment: Got rid of the href, and used a button tag instead. That worked.
<button onclick="changeClass()" class="menuIco"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/menu_icon2.png" width="33" height="33"  /></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...

Got rid of the href, and used a button tag instead. That worked.

```
<button onclick="changeClass()" class="menuIco">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/menu_icon2.png" width="33" height="33" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line `<a href="#" onclick="changeClass()">`

to this: `<a href="#" onclick="changeClass(e)">`

and change the structure of your `changeClass()` function to below and add the given line:

```
function changeClass(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: can you post the `changeClass()` function? it would help a lot solving your problem!

Comment: I just got rid of the href, and used a button tag instead. That worked. <button onclick="changeClass()" class="menuIco"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/menu_icon2.png" width="33" height="33" /></button>